# Sallen-Key low pass filter cutoff frequency

Tags: active-filter

How do I calculate the cutoff frequency and the gain of a second order sallen key low pass filter? For example if I want to have a cutoff 35KHz what would be the values of the two resistances and the two capacitors

[image]

[image]
Using R1=R2=4700 as it was suggested

[image]
As you can see with those values , I have succeeded in creating the low pass filter I want , but the cutoff frequency is very high (I needed 35kHz, the graph is voltage to frequency) . What should I change?

Comment: What gain do you want, exactly?

Comment: @jonk I edited the pictures , By mistake I uploaded a schematic without values. The gain is not the problem at the moment , it is something I will need in the future . My problem now is the cutoff frequency being very high

Comment: Sallen Key topology is different if you want gain, or don't. And if you want equal valued components, or not. I suppose it also helps to know the damping you want, as well. One could just toss you a fish, rather than teach you how to fish. But that would be just doing a design for you. Wouldn't it?

Comment: @jonk I am just asking for help , you can clearly see I put in the work and I am not asking others to do my work for me

Comment: @Maverick98 If you just want to build a filter, I suggest using using a filter calculator. Check out: http://www.analog.com/designtools/en/filterwizard/ (for example). TI and Linear also have them.

Comment: What is going on with R3, R4, and C3? Is this for a single supply rail system? (Your opamp isn't rail to rail.) How is your analysis being done?

Comment: @jonk The circuit that has R3,R4,C3 is used as a virtual ground

Comment: @Maverick98 Which is what makes me wonder about the analysis, itself. I'll post up a short example using LTSpice. You decide what's different.

Comment: Could the issue be that you are expecting the filter to be perfectly flat, but the cutoff is defined as the -3dB point, where the signal is 70% of of the input. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutoff_frequency

Comment: I downvoted this because there's no indication that you have tried to figure this out. A simple search on google takes you to a lot of calculators so it's unclear why you can't apply that information to this circuit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example run from LTSpice for a very simple unity gain, equal component value Sallen Key filter.

[image]

The values used are common values rather than exact values to hit your frequency precisely. But they get close.

Looks about right to me.

---

Here's the chart done differently:

[image]

That may also help you.

---

The reason why the -6 dB point is selected as the "cross-over" has a lot of context. I'm neither competent to explain it fully nor do I have the time to try. I know a few things, is all.

But I can summarize the basics:

1. It's convention and people will understand you better if you use terms they know in the way they know them.
2. If you look at the first graphic I posted here (I suppose, in a way I'll explain later on, the 2nd one also shows this), you can see that the output (the solid line) stays "flat" for a while. Then it goes through a transition period. Then it seems to follow a fairly straight line downward. It would be ***nice*** to find a way to select a point in the transition period that helps delineate between the flat spot *before* and the sloped part *after*. It turns out that the "equidistant" midpoint is the -6 dB point for voltage in a low pass filter.

The filter leaves the input alone (is flat) up until some point. In the first chart shown above, it is pretty flat until it nears \$20\:\textrm{kHz}\$. Then it starts to turn. The turn is finished by the time you get to about \$60\:\textrm{kHz}\$. Once you are there, it's a straight line down at a rate of -40 dB per decade of frequency (for a 2nd order filter.)

The half-voltage point, or -6 dB voltage, is the center of the transition period. And people share this meaning when they speak of filters like this.

I like the 2nd chart I added above because it makes this point in mathematical fashion. Look at the shape of that curve. It is downward curving (2nd derivative is negative) until it reaches some frequency. Then, although continuing to decline, it is upward curving (2nd derivative is positive.) The -6 dB point is exactly where the 2nd derivative transitions from negative to positive -- and hits zero. This is the mathematical reason why this point was chosen.

So this special ***corner point*** has mathematical reasoning, visual reasoning, and convention to support its use.

Comment: But from the graph of Vout , how can we see the cutoff frequency

Comment: @Maverick98 Since this is voltage out, you look for the -6 dB point (and/or where you see -90 degrees.)

Comment: oh I see , compared to my graphs what has changed, is it possible to replace the db on the left with voltage so I can compare?

Comment: @Maverick98 \$10^{\frac{-6}{20}}\approx 0.5\$ so you are looking for where the voltage drops to half.

Comment: But why are you looking for -6dB to see the cutoff frequency and not some other number like -12dB

Comment: @Maverick98 There are lots of good reasons. It would take a chapter or two to put them into context. I'll add some notes to my answer, though. Not much, just a little. But perhaps enough to help out on this question.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the 6dB point is usually considered for filters where power is calculated, such as passive RLC, but for filters where there is virtually no current drawn, or where only the voltage, or the current, are transmitted, the 3dB point is considered as the corner frequency. This makes sense if you consider that the transfer function is usually considered as the magnitude squared, which makes the transition point at half the response. If I am mistaken, please let me know.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen For power, it is -3 dB. For voltage (or current), it is -6 dB. At least, that's been my own understanding.

Comment: @jonk I could be mistaken, however, the corner frequency for a Sallen-Key topology, in particular, and for active filters, in general, is the 3dB point. IIR filters derived from their classical analog counterparts are also at 3dB. FIR filters are at 6dB, but they are a rather special case, only zeroes. And if the power is considered at 6dB, it's because there would be a voltage at 3dB, multiplied with the current at 3dB, power that would not be transmitted through active filters, thus the voltage, or current, remain. In OP's case, fc~22kHz. User pscheidler (in comments) has a good link.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Thanks for pressing back against my comment. I'd like to discuss this further. To get started, have a look at this link: [Sallen-Key Low-pass Filter Design Tool](http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/OPstool.php). Set R1=R2=1E4 and C1=C2=16E-9 and then calculate. Then scroll down and read the cutoff frequency (which I had designed for 1kHz.) It matches. Then move further down to see the charts. Look at the magnitude and phase plots. What do you get for phase and for magnitude at 1kHz on those charts?

Comment: @jonk In that case the resulting transfer function is non-standard, which means you can define whatever point of interest you want/need. An example would be the Linkwitz-Riley filters, which are nothing more than two consecutive Butterworth. The purpose being that the summation of a lowpass and a highpass, for ex., with the same fc, would yield a flat response. Extrapolating, any filter can be designed for a specific fc, even Butterworth can have fc@1.618dB, if that's the requirement, but, in general, if not specified, the 3dB point is considered. I am sorry for prolonging this.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen No, please. I learn a lot from the process and I appreciate your efforts a lot. I do believe that my short explanation was probably wrong in this context, though, and you made me think a little. I believe it isn't for the reasons I mentioned in the comment. However, I do also believe that the web link I provided correctly calculates the corner frequency and correctly calculates the dB at that corner. And I know from a separate book I have (Active-Filter Design) that the design is correct as well as that page's computed corner freq. I'm interested in your thoughts.

Comment: @jonk The transfer function is \$H(s)=39062500/(s^2+12500*s+39062500)\$. Sallen-Key means all-pole, thus the \$\sqrt{a_0}=\omega_c\$: \$\sqrt{39062500}/(2\pi)~995Hz\$. Evaluation of \$|H(j2\pi995)|=0.5\$. Its quality factor is \$\sqrt{b_0}/b_1=0.5\$ thus it's not a classical design, but a custom one, since you imposed the values, rather than fc and Q or \$\zeta\$. If it would have been Butterworth: \$G(s)=(39478417.6)/(s^2+8885.77*s+39478417.6)\$ with \$\sqrt{39478417.6}/(2\pi)=1k\$ and \$|G(j2\pi1k)|=0.7071\$ (unless frequency scaling is applied). Can continue, but, in general...

Comment: ...it comes from the generic transfer function which is along the \$j\omega\$ axis, so it will have roots on both sides. Since only the left-hand side will provide stability, you factor it out as the product of its normal and conjugate, which leads to what I mentioned to be \$H(j\omega)^2\$. Since it's squared, the transition point is considered \$1/2\$ and, when you sqrt() to get to the usable left-hand side roots, it becomes \$1/\sqrt{2}\$. Ex. for Butterworth: \$|H(s)|^2=1\(1+\epsilon^2[(j\omega)/(\omega_c)]^{2N})\$ (\$\epsilon=1\$ here, no freq. scaling, and \$\omega_c=1\$). Thus: ...

Comment: ... for \$N=2\$ => \$\sqrt{|H(j1)|}=1/\sqrt{1+(1/1)^2}=1/\sqrt(2)\$. It's similar for Chebyshev, elliptic, etc, even though special considerations are applied in their case due to the passband ripple nature (but they can be applied frequency scaling, just fine). There are exceptions, Bessel, for ex., but it's meant to be a time-domain filter, like Gaussian (or synchronously tuned, which converge to Gaussian). I think it started with Butterworth's clear and simple way, and I remember from many years ago reading what I said about power vs voltage/current. That's why I said I may be wrong.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Thanks so much for the discussion. I need to read, and then think, about your response. Probably, I need to refer to a few more things, as well. In all, I have confidence that things will settle into a clear picture and I will know better what to add here. I very much appreciate your response. And I need to deal with it as I have time to do that. Please accept my thanks and offer me some time to consider and respond. I will be better for your time and effort. Thanks!

Comment: @jonk I can't find anywhere a PM button, or similar. I would be glad to listen to what you have to say since your answers are always so detailed. Re-reading some of the sources, I can't seem to find anywhere saying that it's "usually 1/sqrt(2)" (or 1/2), Maybe I need to read some more, but it really looks like I was wrong. Now that I think of it, the generic 2nd order transfer function(s) will give the corner frequency through the b0 term (denominator, or a0, depends how you learned), and that frequency will be used to calculate the gain at fc. So, my apologies for jumping to conclusions.

Answer (score 1):

The cutoff frequency is calculated using the following equation.

\begin{equation}
f_c = \frac{1}{2 \pi \sqrt{R_1 R_2 C_1 C_2}}
\end{equation}

Using your current values, you have a cutoff frequency of 338627.5 Hz, which is about ten times higher than desired. Sticking with \$ C_1 = C_2 = 1nF \$ and \$ R_1 = R_2 \$, you should use \$ R_1 = R_2 = 4.7k \Omega \$ to (approximately) get your desired cutoff frequency.

Comment: I have actually tried that  , the thing is the graph is worse than what I posted , see my edit

Comment: Actually, it's not worse at all ! Your cutoff frequency is about 34kHz on your graph.

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume you are trying to design a Butterworth filter which is what's commonly used for audio work to get a maximally flat pass band and a roll off of 6dB/octave/pole (20dB/decade/pole).

Your current design doesn't fall into any standard filter category, neither Butterworth nor Bessel nor Chebychev. It has a Q of 0.5 which is even lower than a Bessel filter giving a gentle corner rolloff. If you want to design an equal value Butterworth filter (R1=R2, C1=C2) then you have to give the op amp a non-inverting gain of 1.586 which raises the Q to a Butterworth specification of 0.707. In this situation the cut-off frequency = 1/(2*PI*R*C).

If you want to have unity gain (as in your design) then for a low pass Butterworth response (Q = 0.707) you must set:-
R1 = R2
and C2 must equal 2*C1
(using your label designations)

and the cut-off frequency now equals 1/(2*PI*Sqrt(R1*R2*C1*C2))

If you require a low pass unity gain filter with a cut-off frequency of 35KHz then I would suggest :-
C1 = 1nF
C2 = 2nF (2 1nFs in parallel)
 and R1 = R2 = 3K3

These values give an fc of about 34kHz where fc is the -3dB point (frequency where the output amplitude is 0.707 times the input amplitude.

The 0.707 is coincidentally the same value as the Q of a Butterworth filter.